# How to bind URL to the HTML hidden button which is dynamically shown by Javascript program

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am working in a simple webpage that requires to download the result as image file in the last step.

I have created a hidden HTML button for downloading result image and set its display to None by CSS. Now I have changed it's visibility from `None` to `block` using a simple JavaScript program.

My program looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style>
    #down_button
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Press the button to start downloading</h1>
   <input type="button" id="down_button" value="Download noww !" >
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my JS file looks like this:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('down_button');

down_button.style.display='block'; //displays the button
```

Is it possible to bind a URL with the button such that whenever a user press the button; the downloading will start in to the browser

Please explain with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to download the image on button click, but be aware, Chrome 65 and above only supports same-origin download links if you use `download` attribute.

```js
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "image.jpg";
link.download = "download.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML [onClick attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) to specify the JavaScript function to run when the button is clicked. In the JS function, redirect your user to the download link. [Here's how to redirect with JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

```
//button HTML
<input type="button" id="down_button" value="Download noww !" onClick="download()">

//JS function
function download(){
   window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Please read through those resources so you can develop an understanding of both binding functionality to a button and redirecting the browser's address.